# Jquery sortable over buttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a bunch of buttons that I want to make sortable (eg, I can rearrange them at will). Here's an the example html code. These buttons are dynamically added so the sort needs to work after addition and deletion of buttons. I've tried using the JQuery sortable but with no luck. Any suggestions on how to do it?

```
    <div id="fav" class="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" aria-labelledby="ui-accordion-accordion-header-0" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="false" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
        <div id="MSFT" symbol="MSFT" exchange="NASDAQ" class="stockButton">
            MSFT
            <span symbol="MSFT" exchange="NASDAQ" class="remove-button">
                x
            </span>
        </div>

        <div id="GOOG" symbol="GOOG" exchange="NASDAQ" class="stockButton">
            GOOG
            <span symbol="GOOG" exchange="NASDAQ" class="remove-button">
                x
            </span>
        </div>

        <div id="YHOO" symbol="YHOO" exchange="NASDAQ" class="stockButton">
            YHOO
            <span symbol="YHOO" exchange="NASDAQ" class="remove-button">
                x
            </span>
        </div>
```

Comment: Post what you tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding the appropriate libraries try:

```
$(function() {
$( "#fav" ).sortable();

$( "#fav" ).append('<span symbol="NEW" exchange="ECH" class="remove-button">x</span>');

});
```

See this http://jsfiddle.net/x4sny/

Comment: Awesome worked! Can you tell me what the .append is there for?

Comment: I used .append to show you that you can dynamically add extra elements and they will automatically be sortable.